# Best practices for passing params in Grails 3

Tags: grails

I'm building a Grails application that starts with loading XML file and based on it generates (dynamically) a form that has checkboxes and a submit button. When a user submits a form, a controller receives the params (checkboxes) and calls a method that reads an Excel file to extract records that matches the params.

**In other words, the scenario I'm trying to implement is that the user submits a form that has some checkboxes (generated dynamically from an XML file), and the params will be passed to a controller that runs a script or a service, which uses these params as criteria to retrieve some rows from an xlsx file and displays these rows in a view.**

My question is what are the best practices for doing that?

- I pass the params from a controller to a service (although I don't
  have a domain class for the data --it can be updated everyday), And
  inject this service into BootStrap.
- I call a method in an external groovy class (in the src folder) that
  uses the params to retrieve data from the Excel file.

Also, what is the most efficient way to parse an Excel or CSV file and extract records with data that match the params? (I can't use DB or domain classes because the Excel file can be updated with new columns over time).

Comment: Your question seems very ambiguous, what you have the issue with passing params?

Comment: @NitinDhomse my question is "what are the best practices for doing that?" I've mentioned two scenarios but I'm not sure which one follows the best practices. Also, I'd appreciate any feedback or suggestion about the way I'm building my app.

Comment: Looks like you are trying to read an .xls file and insert the data in a table. Are you trying to upload the xls files? where do you encounter 'passing param' ?

Comment: @devbd that's right. The scenario I'm trying to implement is that the user submits a form that has some checkboxes (generated based on an XML file), and the params will be passed to a controller that runs a script or a service, which uses these params as criteria to retrieve some rows from an xlsx file and displays these rows in a view. I'm looking for suggestions to do that efficiently based on the best practices.

Comment: ** a service, which uses these params as criteria to retrieve some rows from an xlsx file** ... can you give some code with criteria to fetch rows from xlsx file. Remember, xlsx can not be used as a relational DB

Comment: Give an example of your xlsx file and the code how you read this file.

Answer (score 2):

params in Grails do a good job. However, I would suggest that you consider using command objects. Command objects are like Grails domains but they do not persist data in a physical database. You can easily pass the instantiated command object to the external groovy class (in the src folder) instead of passing params.

You can find more details here: http://guides.grails.org/command-objects-and-forms/guide/index.html

Comment: Thank you for the link. I don't think that works in my case. I don't know how many parameters will be passed from the view to the controller. I can't create a command object when I don't know the properties. All I know is that the params should be treated as a list of strings to be used in searching an xlsx file and retrieving the rows that contain some of these strings. I updated my post with the scenario I'm trying to work on.